# Lua 4.0 undeclared variables and conditional statements

Tags: lua, conditional-statements, lua-4.0

This bit of code is confusing me.

```
print(gogo)
if (gogo == true) then
    print("yes")
elseif (gogo == false) then
    print("no")
end
```

Why is `gogo` evaluating as `true`? Shouldn't it spawn an error instead?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Lua 4.0? That was released in 2000 and 5.x is more widely used.

Comment: I'm working on a mod for Homeworld 2 which was released in 2003.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't evaluate to true and it can't because there is no boolean type in Lua 4.0.

```
print(true) -- prints "nil"
```

Undefined global variables are `nil` by default, so indeed `gogo == true`. They are both `nil`.

Comment: Oops! It seems the "true" and "false" keywords were not added until Lua 5.